# Create a trigger on insert that creates another trigger on a different table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have the following scenario:

I have a table 'a' containing and id and other information. Whenever a new entry is added in table 'a', another table is created named 'a_id'. So for example, if I insert an entry in table 'a' that has the id 1, another table named 'a_1' is automatically created. Table 'a_1' contains an id of it's own, but the only relation with the first table is it's name. I need to insert in a separate table, whenever something is inserted in 'a_1' (or 'a_2', or 'a_3', or...) the id of the new entry in 'a_1' and the original id form table 'a' (in this case 1).

The solution I found for this is to create an insert trigger for table 'a' that creates another insert trigger for any subsequent tables created from it ('a_1', 'a_2', etc). The trigger on those tables would get the id of the new entry and the whatever is in the table name after '_', and would insert those values in a separate table.

Is it possible to do something like this (create a trigger that creates triggers on other tables named dynamically)?

Comment: Possible but not necessarily a good idea. Instead of setting up coinciding identifier names, you should look for ways to link these tables declaratively and in a normalised structure - the entire language is built and focused around this approach and as long as you too follow it, you can benefit from all of its built-in functionalities and optimisations.

Comment: How about creating only tables `a` and `b`. Whenever `a.id` gets generated for a new record, you want it to propagate to `b.a_id`, which in turn generates b's own `b.id`. You'd normally accumulate `a_id` and `b_id` pairs in table `c`, but that's already happening in `b`, so there's no need for that. What you'd normally get from `select id from a_1;` you get from `select id from b where a_id=1` - the `b.a_id` column differentiates between records the same way separation into standalone a_1, a_2... tables would.

Comment: This is the database implementation that the solution I'm integrating is using. I know it's not the best way to work with relational tables and if it were up to me I would have done this in a simpler way (like what you recommended for example), but I'm constrained to this database structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a basic starting structure like this: [(demo for all below)](https://dbfiddle.uk/jTcfsCb0)

```sql
create table a(
  id int generated by default as identity primary key,
  payload text default gen_random_uuid()::text);

create table a_gen_collector(
  a_id int references a(id) 
           on delete cascade
           on update cascade,
  a_gen_id int); --note this collects data from different a_N tables, so no FK
```

[Dynamic SQL `EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) with [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) lets you do all that. [Named dollar quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) come useful with all the nesting:

```sql
create function tgf_a_gen() returns trigger language plpgsql as $f_1$
begin 
  execute format(
    $dynamic_sql_1$ 
     create table %1$I (id int generated by default as identity primary key);
     create function tgf_%1$I_collect() returns trigger language plpgsql as $f_2$
     begin 
        insert into a_gen_collector (a_id,a_gen_id) values (%2$L,NEW.id);
        return null;
     end $f_2$;
     create trigger tg_a_gen_collect after insert on %1$I
     for each row execute function tgf_%1$I_collect();
    $dynamic_sql_1$, 
    concat('a_',NEW.id), 
    NEW.id);
  return null;
end $f_1$;

create trigger tg_a_gen after insert on a
for each row execute function tgf_a_gen();
```

1. You might need to build out the trigger structure to emulate foreign key [cascading](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-REFERENCES-REFACT-CASCADE) behaviour between the collector table and all the `a_N`'s. You could even reverse the link and make the collector centrally responsible for generating all the `a_N.id`, while the `a_N` tables only receive it into a foreign key column. That way you can update those on the collector table and the change will cascade to the corresponding `a_N`.
2. You might want to also handle dropping and renaming the `a_N` tables in response to updates and deletes from the main `a` table. Otherwise both of these operations are bound to orphan their corresponding table (`a.id` will no longer coincide with any `a_N` table).